# Variations of Parameter problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble with this variation of parameters problem in my differential equations class:

Find the general solution to $y''+9y'=3\tan(3t)$

Basically, I got down to the integrals where I had the integral of sin(x) and an integral of sin(x)tan(x). As to the latter integral, I do not know how to do it or whether or not these are the correct integrals to the problem.

Comment: Well, assuming the integral is correct, would it help to rewrite $\sin x\tan x$ as $\sec x-\cos x$?

Comment: Is this supposed to be $y'' + 9y = 3\tan(3t)$?

Answer (score 1):

First, there appears to be an issue with the problem as written (no solution), and I think from your comments, you meant:

$$y''+ 9 y = 3 \tan(3t)$$

I will map out the steps for you and have you fill in the details.

We are asked to solve this using Variation of Parameters (VoP), given:

$$\tag 1 y''+9y = 3\tan(3t)$$

**Step 1**

Find the homogenous solution to $(1)$, so we have:

$$\tag 2 y''+ 9y = 0$$

This yields:

$$y_h = y(x)= c_1 \cos (3 t) + c_2 \sin (3 t)$$

**Step 2**

We are now going to make use of VoP, so we set: $y_1 = \cos(3t)$ and $y_2 = \sin(3t)$ from $y_h$ and $f(t) = 3 \tan(3 t)$ from $(1)$.

We calculate the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$, yielding $W(\cos(3 t), \sin(3 t)) = 3$.

Using VoP, we have:

$\begin{align}
u_1 & = \int \dfrac{-y_2 f}{W(\cos(3 t), \sin(3 t))} dt \\
& = \int -\sin(3 t) \tan(3 t)~ dt \\
& = \dfrac{1}{3} \sin (3 t)+\dfrac{1}{3} \log \left(\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right)-\dfrac{1}{3} \log \left(\sin \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right) 
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
u_2 & = \int \dfrac{y_1 f}{W(\cos(3 t), \sin(3 t))} ~dt \\
& =  \int \cos(3 t) \tan(3 t)~dt \\
& = -\dfrac{1}{3} \cos (3 t)
\end{align}$

Now, $y_p$ is given by:

$\begin{align}
y_p & = y_1 u_1 + y_2 u_2 \\
& = (\cos(3t))\left(\dfrac{1}{3} \sin (3 t)+\dfrac{1}{3} \log \left(\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right)-\dfrac{1}{3} \log \left(\sin \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right) \right) + (\sin(3 t))\left( -\dfrac{1}{3} \cos (3 t) \right) \\
& = (\cos(3t))\left(\dfrac{1}{3} \log \left(\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right)-\dfrac{1}{3} \log \left(\sin \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right) \right) 
\end{align}$

**Step 3**

Our final solution is given by:

$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = c_1 \cos (3 t) + c_2 \sin (3 t) + \dfrac{1}{3} \left(\cos (3 t) \log \left(\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right)-\cos (3 t) \log \left(\sin \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\dfrac{3 t}{2}\right)\right)\right)$

Comment: Awesome answer, Amzoti!